# How do I add an array to an XML object in Coldfusion?

Tags: xml, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

I'm blanking on the best way to take an array and add it to an XML object.

I'm starting with an XML object that has empty nodes. Example XML:

```
<Request>
    ... other nodes ...
    <Test></Test>
    <Items>
      <Item>
        <Class></Class>
        <Weight></Weight>
      </Item>
    </Items>
    ... other nodes ...
</Request>
```

I have parsed the XML above and can set data on the object just fine:

```
<cfset ParsedXML.Request.Test.XMLText = "Test">
```

Which results in this:

```
<Request>
    ... other nodes ...
    <Test>Test</Test>
    <Items>
      <Item>
        <Class></Class>
        <Weight></Weight>
      </Item>
    </Items>
    ... other nodes ...
</Request>
```

So far so good. However, when I want to take a Coldfusion array and add it to XMLChildren, I'm running into a problem. So say I take an array of items:

```
<cfset ItemsArray = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset ItemsArray[1] = {
    "Class": 55,
    "Weight": 100
}>
<cfset ItemsArray[2] = {
    "Class": 55,
    "Weight": 200
}>
```

And then I want to loop through that array to create new nodes inside ResponseNodes.Request.Items.XMLChildren:

```
<cfset ItemRow = 1>
<cfloop array="#ItemsArray#" index="i">
    <cfset ParsedXML.Request.Items.Item[ItemRow].Class.XMLText = i.Class>
    <cfset ParsedXML.Request.Items.Item[ItemRow].Weight.XMLText = i.Weight>
    <cfset ItemRow = ItemRow + 1>
</cfloop>
```

I am getting this error:

> The index of a child element is out of range.
>    There are only 1 children under this node.
>    Index 2 is out of the allowed range [1-1].

I've also tried XmlElemNew() but keep running into `The right hand side of the assignment is not of type XML Node.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish? You need to treat any node you are trying to add to add (`Item`, `Class`, `Weight` etc) to your xml as a `XmlChildren`.

```
<cfset ItemsArray = [
  {"Class": 55, "Weight": 100},
  {"Class": 55, "Weight": 200},
  {"Class": 55, "Weight": 300}
]>

<cfxml variable="ParsedXML">
  <cfoutput>
  <Request>
      <Test></Test>
      <Items>
      </Items>
  </Request>
  </cfoutput>
</cfxml>
<cfset ParsedXML.Request.Test.XMLText = "Test">
<cfset ItemRow = 1>
<cfloop array="#ItemsArray#" index="i">
  <cfset ParsedXML.Request.Items.XmlChildren[ItemRow] = XmlElemNew(ParsedXML,"Item")> 
  <cfset ParsedXML.Request.Items.XmlChildren[ItemRow].XmlChildren[1] = XmlElemNew(ParsedXML,"Class")> 
  <cfset ParsedXML.Request.Items.XmlChildren[ItemRow].XmlChildren[2] = XmlElemNew(ParsedXML,"Weight")> 
  <cfset ParsedXML.Request.Items.XmlChildren[ItemRow].XmlChildren[1].XMLText = i.Class>
  <cfset ParsedXML.Request.Items.XmlChildren[ItemRow].XmlChildren[2].XMLText = i.Weight>
  <cfset ItemRow += 1>
</cfloop>
<cfdump var="#ParsedXML#">
```

[**DEMO**](https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=029e5d1b-d8af-42cc-b178-e0d619a89b64/61c8b35d-f4b6-4092-9436-601ab76d0726/0f32384f-3840-4b74-a062-ab13fed7edbe.cfm)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I should have elaborated on my XMLElemNew() attempts but I can see now what I failed to do was first add the Item node and then the children (Class and Weight). Thank you for taking the time to answer, it was a huge help!